# How to hide/show div by Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 3 Divs (screens i.e A ,B C ) ..each screen has a button..I want to change the screen on button click..How can this be achieved by using javascript jquery no C#...All the screen must have the same location...

Explanantion :

1 div should be displayed at a time .. If Screen A is displaying Screen B and C should be hidden.. on button click of screen A the Screen A should get disappear and Screen B becomes visible .. Screen B has two button if button1 is press Screen A should appear and If button2 is press Screen C should appear...

```js
    <div>
        This is Screen A<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go to Screen B" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            This is Screen B</div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Go to Screen A" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Go to Screen C" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            This is Screen&nbsp; C</div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Go to Screen B" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Use update panel and on button click set the other two div false using jquery or javascript.

Comment: First try by yourself then ask question.. and also put your code which you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `JavaScript`. [FiddlerDEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq0thtbt/)

```js
function Show(id)
{
    document.getElementById("divA").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("divB").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("divC").style.display = "none";      
    
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.clsDiv
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divA">
 This is Screen A<br />
 <input type="button" value="Go to Screen B" onClick="Show('divB')" />
</div>
<div id="divB" class="clsDiv">
   
 This is Screen B<br />
 
 <input type="button" value="Go to Screen A" onClick="Show('divA')"/>
 <br />
 <input type="button" value="Go to Screen C" onClick="Show('divC')"/>
</div>
<div id="divC" class="clsDiv">
 <div>
  This is Screen&nbsp; C</div>
 <br />
 <input type="button" value="Go to Screen B" onClick="Show('divB')" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give classes to dives and give that class in jquery code.this will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Button1").click(function(){
        $("div-a class").hide();
        $("div-c class").hide();
        $("div-b class").show();
    });

   $("#Button2").click(function(){
        $("div-b class").hide();
        $("div-c class").hide();
        $("div-a class").show();
    });

   $("#Button2").click(function(){
        $("div-b class").hide();
        $("div-a class").hide();
        $("div-c class").show();
    });

   $("#Button2").click(function(){
        $("div-a class").hide();
        $("div-c class").hide();
        $("div-b class").show();
    });
});
```